# How to get the upper and lower bounds of a graph?

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions, maple

Size of a population is given by $N(t)=10+2e^{-0.3t}sin t$

The size is measured in millions and time is in weeks.

Plotting the graph in Maple gives me this image:

[image: Graph of N(t) versus t]

How do I get the upper and bounds on the size of population using minima and maxima concept?

Comment: assuming $t>0$, the range of $N(t)$ will be between $8$ and $12$

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find derivative $N'(t)=-0.6e^{-0.3t}\sin t+2e^{-0.3t}\cos t$ then you need to find all solutions for $N'(t)=0$ which is equivalent to solving $-0.6\sin t+2\cos t=0$ or $\tan x=\frac{10}{3}$. The solutions of this equation are $t=\arctan{\frac{10}{3}}+n\pi, n= 0, 1 ,2, ...$. These are the points that you need to check for minimum and maximum. The most interesting for you are probably the first few solutions as $N(t)$ tends to $10$ as $t$ tends to infinity.